# Recursing over a rich-text syntax tree with PHP

Tags: php, recursion, tree

The webapp I'm working on in my spare time has a rich text editor with custom elements added. For saving to the server, it generates what I'm calling a syntax tree, which is a JSON object. Here is one such object:

```json
[[["Some text"],["More text"],[{"type":"bold","value":["Bold text"]}],[{"type":"bold","value":[{"type":"italic","value":["Bold and italic text"]}]}],[{"type":"bold","value":[{"type":"italic","value":["Italic stuff"]},"blah blah "]},"this is not bold ",{"type":"italic","value":["italic"]},{"type":"bold","value":[{"type":"italic","value":["boldno"]}]}],[{"type":"bold","value":[{"type":"italic","value":["image comes next"]}]}],["hello",{"type":"image","value":"https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/k/ko-show/20200828/20200828140706.jpg"},"there"],[{"type":"mention","value":"austinburk"}," is an id call"]],[["more text lines"]]]
```

On the first level, each list is one "section". Within each section, each list contains a single line.

[image: How it renders]

Now, we have the initial generation of these objects working fine. We also have the rendering working. Both of those are done on the client-side with JavaScript. However, we still need to have the API process them in order to do things like sanitization (changing values if needed), validation, notifying of mentions and so on, in order to produce two things: a plaintext representation and a new, "processed" version of the object that will be stored and returned to the client.

I've been trying for about a week now with little to no success to figure out a way to do it. It would let me take an input tree and process it something like this (forgive the mspaint quality):

[image: badly drawn diagram showing an object being processed through a filter function]

Things like bold and italic would be passed through. "text" type isn't stored in the object.

Where do I even go from here?

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure if this can be done recursively. I feel like my eventual solution may be something like disassembling the structure into something more flat and then reassembling it afterward somehow, like giving each element a key and referencing sub-elements by that key

Comment: I am not sure what you want as output. Can you provide the output you expect for the given concrete example?

Comment: The only sane way to deal with data structures of arbitrary depth is with recursion. Even if you want to flatten such a structure, you would do it with recursion.

Comment: I am seeing a possibility that the data can be turned into multidimensional array also If you were to treat the data as string and use lot of getting data between this and that and str replace can help you clean up the data...even turn it into readable html